# Get and set current input value without Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is possible to get the current input value without jQuery?
I mean, i don't wanna use document.getElementById / class. i wanna get element by input tag.

I have this implemented with jQuery:

```
    $(document).on('keyup', 'input', function(e) {
        console.log($(this).val());
    })
```

And is works for every input.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" value="">
    <input type="text" value="">
</div>
```

I don't know how i can transform jQuery code into pure javascript code. I try this:

```
    document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
        console.log(this.value);
    });
```

But, is working only for the first input. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you dynamically creating input elements that warrant the need for a delegate binding?

Comment: no, i don't add them dynamically, but i get the answer, but also thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the function `querySelectorAll` to get the whole set of elements.  Then, you need to loop over those elements and bind the necessary event.

The function `querySelector` returns the first found element only.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
    console.log(this.value);
  });
})
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `document.getElementsByTagName` and loop through them

```js
for (var i=0; i< document.getElementsByTagName("input").length; i++) {
  document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
    console.log(this.value);
  });
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" value="">
  <input type="text" value="">
</div>
```